# vaadin Grid select of a row by index number

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

How can I select programmatically a row by index in vaadin grid flow?

Isn't there a method like

`grid.setSelectedIndex(2);`
for example?

Thank you

Comment: What type of DataProvider are you using? If you're using `setItems` that's a ListDataProvider

Comment: Hi Hawk, yes I am using `setItems`. My objective is to show that a row is already selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vaadin 14 when you use ListDataProvider, this is still relatively simple.

```
   grid.setItems(..);
   var dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<Bean>) grid.getDataProvider()
   var item = dataProvider.getItems().get(2);
   grid.select(item);
```

If your `DataProvider` is lazy one, then some more boilerplate code is needed to form a `Query` objecht and `dataProvider.fetch(..)` with `Query` is needed.

Vaadin 17 introduced concept (the latest version is now 19, 20 to be released soon) of `DataView` [Java API](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/20.0.0.beta1/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/DataView.html) to get rid of the boilerplate code. This adds some convenience methods to do for example selection of item at index 2. This works also with lazy data providers. Pseudocode example.

```
var dataView = grid.setItems(..);
var item = dataView.getItem(2);
grid.select(item);
```

Comment: Can you provide some example for Vaadin 14 to how can i select some item in lazy-load Grid with Query by ItemId or by row Id?